# Change img src attribute value in loop - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, src, attr

I have a carousel with images which I'd like the src attributes values to be replaced with other data-src attributes values depending on the window width.

```
<div id="mainCarousel">
<img class="img-carousel" src="img/carousel-main-img2.jpg" data-src="img/carousel-main-datasrc-1.jpg" data-srctwo="img/carousel-main-datasrctwo-1.jpg">
<img class="img-carousel" src="img/carousel-main-img3.jpg" data-src="img/carousel-main-datasrc-2.jpg" data-srctwo="img/carousel-main-datasrctwo-2.jpg">
```

```
function carouselImages() {

      // set window width in a variable
      var winWidth = $(window).width();
      // set img DOM element in a variable
      var imgCarousel = $('#mainCarousel .img-carousel');
      // declare empty variable for img 'data-src' attribute
      var dataSrc = $();
      // declare empty variable for img 'data-srcTwo' attribute 
      var dataSrcTwo = $();

      //set loop which will iterate on each img DOM element
      for(var i=0; i<imgCarousel.length; i++) {
        // set first width range condition
        if(winWidth > 400 && winWidth < 768) {
          // if width matches condition, store the value of each DOM element's 'data-src' attribute in previously declared variable
          dataSrc = imgCarousel[i].attr('data-src');
          // replace DOM element's 'src' attribute's value with 'data-src' attribute's value 
          imgCarousel[i].attr('src', dataSrc);
        }

        // set second width range condition  
        else if (winWidth >= 768) {
          // if width matches condition, store the value of each DOM element's 'data-src' attribute in previously declared variable
          dataSrcTwo = imgCarousel[i].attr('data-srcTwo');
          // replace DOM element's 'src' attribute's value with 'data-src' attribute's value
          imgCarousel[i].attr('src', dataSrcTwo);
        }

      }

    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
      carouselImages();
    });
    $(window).resize(function () {
       carouselImages();
    });
```

What I want to achieve is that the images `src` values get replaced with `data-src` values when the window width is between 401px and 767px, and with `data-srctwo` values when the window width is `>= 768px`.

I tried to be as logical as possible when structuring my function. But it just doesn't work. The src attributes values don't change at all neither when reducing the screen and refreshing, nor when directly resizing the browser window. Plus, I get the following error message

> imgCarousel[i].attr is not a function

Could anybody tell me what's actually wrong with the logic behind my function; And why I get the error message as I don't think you necessarily need to have a function inside a condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var imgCarousel = $('#mainCarousel .img-carousel');` is an array of matched elements. Its only the DOM element not an jquery object. So when looping over it & applying `attr` it will thrown an error.

You need to convert it to jquery object before applying `.attr` method on it.

You can refer to the current element by either of the following way

```
$(imgCarousel[i]).attr('data-src');
```

Comment: `$(this)` won't work when the OP is using a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are using jquery function ,so don't need `for loop` .Use `each` will help you more easily and set src with current element by `$(this)`

```
 imgCarousel.each(function(){
      if(winWidth > 400 && winWidth < 768) {
          data-src = $(this).attr("data-src");
          $(this).attr('src',data-src);

        }

        // set second width range condition  
        else if (winWidth >= 768) {
         data-srcTwo = $(this).attr("data-srcTwo");
         $(this).attr('src',data-srcTwo);

        }
 });
```

Comment: It's indeed more simple to write with .each(). I thought 'for' loop was processed faster by the browser that each() function.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(imgCarousel[i])` instead of `imgCarousel[i]`.
`imgCarousel[i]` is a tag, `$(imgCarousel[i])` is an jquery object

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the DOM element reference to JQuery object before you use the `$.attr()` function in following way:

```
function carouselImages() {

      // set window width in a variable
      var winWidth = $(window).width();
      // set img DOM element in a variable
      var imgCarousel = $('#mainCarousel .img-carousel');
      // declare empty variable for img 'data-src' attribute
      var dataSrc = $();
      // declare empty variable for img 'data-srcTwo' attribute 
      var dataSrcTwo = $();

      //set loop which will iterate on each img DOM element
      for(var i=0; i<imgCarousel.length; i++) {
        // set first width range condition
        if(winWidth > 400 && winWidth < 768) {
          // if width matches condition, store the value of each DOM element's 'data-src' attribute in previously declared variable
          dataSrc = $(imgCarousel[i]).attr('data-src');
          // replace DOM element's 'src' attribute's value with 'data-src' attribute's value 
          $(imgCarousel[i]).attr('src', dataSrc);
        }

        // set second width range condition  
        else if (winWidth >= 768) {
          // if width matches condition, store the value of each DOM element's 'data-src' attribute in previously declared variable
          dataSrcTwo = $(imgCarousel[i]).attr('data-srcTwo');
          // replace DOM element's 'src' attribute's value with 'data-src' attribute's value
          $(imgCarousel[i]).attr('src', dataSrcTwo);
        }

      }

    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
      carouselImages();
    });
    $(window).resize(function () {
       carouselImages();
    });
```